# Creating nested json objects in Java

Tags: java, android, json

I need to create JSON like below to send with a POST request. So far I tried to accomplish this by using Org.Json library

```
"Configs": {
 "TeamEvents": {
    "3050": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
    "3052": [1,2,8],
    "3054": [4]
 }
```

4 digit numbers are ids.
However I could not grasp how can I do this part. I've created TeamEvents JSONObject and added id's and arrays with JSONObject.put() method but I dont know how can I pass that TeamEvents object to Configs. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to achieve this is simply serialize object to JSON string with any popular JSON library such as Jackson, Gson and so on.

First, construct a nested map of objects as follows:

```java
Map<String, Object> teamEventMap = new HashMap<>();
teamEventMap.put("3050", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8));
teamEventMap.put("3052", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 8));
teamEventMap.put("3054", Arrays.asList(4));

Map<String, Object> configMap = new HashMap<>();
configMap.put("TeamEvents", teamEventMap);

Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
resultMap.put("Configs", configMap);
```

Then just leverage JSON library for serialization without directly operating JSON objects:

```java
// By using Jackson
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(resultMap));

// By using Gson
Gson gson = new Gson();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(resultMap));
```

Both two JSON libraries produce the same output as expected:

> {"Configs":{"TeamEvents":{"3054":[4],"3052":[1,2,8],"3050":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}}}

---

One of the benefits for this way resides it is easy to switch to another JSON library without much code change.

Answer (score 1):

You've basically already found your solution, you just haven't realised it!

You can add a JSONObject to a JSONObject.

So you can create your teamEvents JSONObject, .put("each id", value) , then create a new configs JsonObject, and configsObject.put("TeamEvents", teamEventsObject).

So like this...

```
JSONObject teamEventsObject.put("3050", [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]);
teamEventsObject.put("3052", [1,2,8]); 
... etc

JSONObject configsObject.put("Configs", teamEventsObject);
```

Or indeed as Enes has implied, you could do it via creation of java POJOs, then serialize those objects into json, eg. with the Jackson objectMapper. This would be a more solid 'contract' than hardcoding string JSONObjects, but both ways achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Gson Library](https://github.com/google/gson).

Check [user guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) for more complex example.

### Simple Example

```
class DataClass {
    private int code = 1;
    private String name = "abc";
    DataClass() {
        // no-args constructor
    }
}

// Serialization
DataClass data = new DataClass();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(data);

// ==> json is {"code":1,"name":"abc"}
    
// Deserialization
DataClass data = gson.fromJson(json, DataClass.class);
```